# What is naming convention for DTOs in a webservice

Tags: oop, design-patterns, naming-conventions, design-principles

I'm designing a restful web service and I was wondering what should I name my DTOs. Can I use suffixes like Request and Response for them? for example for addUser service, there will be 2 DTOs named: AddUserRequest and AddUserResponse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your organization already have a schema that describes a canonical user that you pass in?  If that's what you're using, of course you would use the name from that schema.  Otherwise, describe them just as you would any class or schema element.

Note that since a DTO doesn't contain its own methods, you probably would not give it a name with an action verb.

However, consider calling them AddUserRequest and AddUserResponse, especially if the method requires more info than just your regular user DTO.  This fits with the Interface Segregation Principle in that your interface parameters should be specifically tailored to the request itself (it shouldn't require elements that are unrelated to the request; and you shouldn't have  function-type parameters that change the request, those should be extracted into their own calls.)  The AddUserRequest might then contain an element called User that holds the user-specific data, and another element holding the set of other associated data on the request, perhaps groups or access permissions, that sort of thing.

Answer (score 1):

DTOs (Data Transfer Object) are like POJOs(Plain Old Java Objects). It should only have `getters` and `setters` and not any business logic.

From Wikepedia:

> A data transfer object is an object that carries data between
>   processes. The motivation for its use is that communication between
>   processes is usually done resorting to remote interfaces (e.g., web
>   services), where each call is an expensive operation. Because the
>   majority of the cost of each call is related to the round-trip time
>   between the client and the server, one way of reducing the number of
>   calls is to use an object (the DTO) that aggregates the data that
>   would have been transferred by the several calls, but that is served
>   by one call only.
>
> The difference between data transfer objects and business objects or
>   data access objects is that a DTO does not have any behavior except
>   for storage and retrieval of its own data (mutators and accessors).
>   DTOs are simple objects that should not contain any business logic
>   that would require testing.
>
> This pattern is often incorrectly used outside of remote interfaces.
>   This has triggered a response from its author[3] where he reiterates
>   that the whole purpose of DTOs is to shift data in expensive remote
>   calls.

So ideally for those actions you should create some helpers or you can add those as controllers.

Answer (score 1):

Since it is a RESTful service, ideally the user addition/creation request should send back 201 created HTTP status code , with userId in location header and no response body. For the request, you could name it like UserDetails or UserData or simply User. Refer https://pontus.ullgren.com/view/Return_Location_header_after_resource_creation